# multiple runs of inference model using saved checkpoint produces stochastic errors - Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am running Tensorflow 0.12.1 on a GPU. I have a trained Deep CNN model whose weights I've saved using a  checkpoint file. During inference, I reload the saved checkpoint using `restorer.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(FLAGS.train_dir))`.  The code seems to run without issues, but everytime I re-run the script, I'm getting screwed up outputs. AFAIK, I do not shuffle my test set inputs. The inputs are being loaded and fed to the network properly. It is just the output of different runs of the CNN on the same test set using the same order is producing very different outputs.  I'm perplexed! Also, how do I execute a graph loaded with saved checkpoint without running an `init_op` during inference? It seems my code requires all global and local variables to be initialized before execution. (I initialize first, and then only restore the checkpoint!).Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import os.path
from datetime import datetime
import time
import random
import json

from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes


from modelFCNN3 import model 

def read_input(inp_queue,height=224,width=224,channels=3, mask=False):
  value = tf.read_file(inp_queue)
  image = tf.image.decode_png(value)
  image =  tf.image.resize_images(image, [height, width],method=2)
  image = tf.cast(image, tf.uint8)
  image.set_shape([height,width,channels])
  image = tf.reshape(image,[height,width,channels])
  if mask:
      image = tf.to_float(tf.greater_equal(image,128))
      image = tf.cast(image,tf.float32)
  else:
      image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)
      image = tf.cast(image,tf.float32)
  return image




if __name__ == '__main__':

    tf.reset_default_graph()

    with open('X_test.json', 'r') as infile:
        X_test = json.load(infile)

    with open('y_test.json', 'r') as infile:
        y_test = json.load(infile)

    imagelist = ops.convert_to_tensor(X_test, dtype=dtypes.string)
    labellist = ops.convert_to_tensor(y_test, dtype=dtypes.string)

    input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([imagelist, labellist],
                                            num_epochs=1,
                                            shuffle=False)

    image = read_input(input_queue[0],height=224,width=224,channels=3, mask=False)

    label = read_input(input_queue[1],height=224,width=224,channels=1, mask=True)

    images_batch, labels_batch = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
        enqueue_many=False,shapes=None, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)

    global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
    images = tf.placeholder_with_default(images_batch, shape=[None, 224,224,3])
    labels = tf.placeholder_with_default(labels_batch, shape=[None, 224,224,1])

    restorer = tf.train.Saver()

    logits = model(images).logits
    labels = tf.cast(labels,tf.int32)
    labels.set_shape([FLAGS.batch_size,224,224,1])

    valid_prediction = tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(logits), dimension=3)
    valid_prediction.set_shape([FLAGS.batch_size,224,224])

    meanIOU,update_op_mIOU= tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_mean_iou(tf.cast(valid_prediction,tf.int32), tf.squeeze(labels),FLAGS.num_classes)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    init_locals = tf.local_variables_initializer()


    with tf.Session() as sess:

        sess.run([init, init_locals])

        restorer.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(FLAGS.train_dir))
        print("Model restored.")


        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord,sess=sess)
        summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.train_dir, sess.graph)

        try:
            step = 0
            avg = []
            while not coord.should_stop():
                myimg, predimg, mylbl= sess.run([images,valid_prediction,labels])
                mIOU,_ = sess.run([meanIOU,update_op_mIOU])
                avg.append(mIOU)

            step += 1

        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('Done training -- epoch limit reached')

        finally:

            coord.request_stop()
            coord.join(threads)
            sess.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running on same machine or different machine
            #saver = tf.train.Saver()

The following comment is in tensorflow docs 
            #NOTE: Restarting training from saved meta_graph only works if the device assignments have not changed.
            #saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(metafile)